# how to assign a hasMany role check in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

In my website

I have a InitiatorController which looks like thi

```
class InitiatorController extends Controller
{

 use ExchangerateTrait;
 public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('role:sales'); // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
}

 public function getIndex(){


            return redirect('initiator/home');
 }

}
```

Right now After authenticating I am checking if the user role is `sales` or not in Role middleware .

My role middleware looks like this.

```
class Role
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role){

            if ($request->user()->role != $role){

                    if($role=="collector" || $role=="admin" )
                    return Redirect::to('/');  
                    if($role=="director" || $role=="admin" )
                    return Redirect::to('/');  
                    if($role=="admin1" || $role=="admin" )
                    return Redirect::to('/');
                    if($role=="admin2" || $role=="admin" )
                    return Redirect::to('/');
                    if($role=="sales" || $role=="admin" )
                     return Redirect::to('/');
                    if($role=="developer" || $role=="admin" )
                     return Redirect::to('/');


            }

            return $next($request);
        }

}
```

Now I have a situation where role is `director` but he is also a sales man , How do i tackle this.

**First Idea**
in controller

if I some how send an array of roles to the middleware  something like this

```
$roles = array('director,sales,teamlead');
$this->middleware('role:$roles');
```

and then in Middle ware I can check like

```
if(in_array ($request->user()->role,$roles)){
      //do some thing
}
else
{
   //redirect to login 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean how to get multiple roles in middleware?

Comment: @Chay22 yes something like that , Suppose in Initiator controller there are some functions that should be accessed only By team leader who are also a sales man , How Can I check that  ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I Implemented a role middleware:

RoleMiddleware.php

```
class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $routeRoles = $this->getRolesForRoute($request->route());
        $user = $request->user();
        if (!$routeRoles || (isset($user) && $user->isPermitted($routeRoles))) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        abort(401);
    }

    /**
     * Function to get the roles of the requested route.
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Routing\Route $route
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getRolesForRoute($route)
    {
        $routeAction = $route->getAction();
        return isset($routeAction['roles']) ? $routeAction['roles'] : null;
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get(
            '/post/delete/{pageId}',
            [
                'as' => 'deleteNavigation',
                'uses' => 'NavigationController@postDeleteNavigation',
                'roles' => 'Administrator'
            ]
        );
```

note that 'roles' can be array or a string

and then in User.php the eloquent model of user:

```
/**
 * Function to check whether this user is permitted
 * a route or not.
 *
 * @param array|string|null $routeRoles Route roles.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isPermitted($routeRoles)
{
    $routeRoles = strtolower($routeRoles);
    if (empty($routeRoles)) {
        return true;
    }

    $userRole = strtolower($this->role()->getResults()->name);
    if (is_array($routeRoles)) {
        foreach ($routeRoles as $routeRole) {
            if ($routeRole == $userRole) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($routeRoles == $userRole) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Define an inverse one-to-many relationship.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

I know It's a slightly different logic than yours but it works fine for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with L5.2, but I think it has no difference between these. If I understand your question correctly, you can insert multiple middleware params just like

```
$this->middleware('role:sales,leader'); //so on separated by commas
```

Just in case you're using PHP >= 5.6, it has new cool features that I often use: [Variable-length argument list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new). `...$roles`

For below 5.6, I guess `func_get_args` might help also

Then something in middleware (also adapting my own broken logic route middleware)

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  array  $roles
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    if ($user && $this->isAllowed($user, $roles)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return view('errors.403');
}
```

---

Continue seeing my broken logic

```
/**
 * Check if current user role is allowed 
 * 
 * @param  string      $user    current requested user
 * @param  null|array  $roles
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isAllowed($user, $roles)
{
    $roles = $this->extractRoles($roles);

    //Check for role exsistance
    if (! $this->roleExists($roles)) {
        return false;
    }

    //Override this check if user has super privillege
    if ($user->role === $this->superRole()) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (str_contains($role, $user->role)) {
            return true;
        }  
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Convert given roles to an array
 * 
 * @param  null|array  $roles
 * @return array
 */
protected function extractRoles($roles)
{
    $super = $this->superRole();
    foreach($roles as &$role)
        $roles = strtolower($role);

    //if no argument set on middleware return
    //the super role
    return count($roles) == 0 ? [$super] : $roles;
}

/**
 * Check if role is defined in config file
 * 
 * @param  null|array  $roles
 * @return bool
 */
protected function roleExists($roles)
{
    $roleList = config('roles.roles');
    foreach($roleList as &$role)
        $roleList = strtolower($role);

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($roles, $roleList)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Set the super privillege role
 * 
 * @return string 
 */
public function superRole()
{
    $super = config('roles.super');

    if (is_array($super)) {
        $super = head($super);
    }

    return (string) strtolower($super);
}
```

Comment: this is on controller level right, like this controller can be accessed by certain roles, but how can I restrict  each function with the permission  , Like certain function has to be accessed only by certain role

Comment: I separate that one to `Policies` (gate thingy) just to make my code cleaner (for me atleast XD)

Comment: Do i need to maintain a database with function name and the id ? who can access them

Comment: Yes policy is what My manager was talking about but in general terms he doesnt know coding so he couldnt explain me how i should design that

Comment: [matt stauffer's blog](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1) explaining ACL that taught me these things in the first place. It's hard to list the abilities one per controller method, so I use model too, instead of just Policy alone.

Comment: I am already going through his bolg :D , Its going to be hell of a work for me to format the complete app since it has 45 controller :(

Comment: If most purpose is to restrict such role to some routes, middleware is your best friend. If you're going to hide some feature on site (blade), model could intercept it. If you want to flexible enough on how to restrict such as showing modal dialog if user isn't logged in, policy is the way to go. But, it's 45 * 6 (roles). I get your feeling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115114/discussion-between-vikram-and-chay22).

Answer (score 0):

**You can define relationships in model as function and use that function to check the hasMany role.**

As shown in laravel 5 docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many